# represent random attribute initialization

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I am creating a class diagram where one of the attributes is initialized to a random value.  What is the convention in a class diagram for showing that an attribute is initialized to a random value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In UML, the default value of an attribute is a so-called `ValueSpecification`, which includes among others literal values (String, Number, ...),

[image]

as well as `Expressions`/`OpaqueExpressions` where you can specify an expression in some language, include programming and natural ones.

[image]

For further reading see Chapter 8  - Values in [UML Specs](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5/)

Comment: The discussion of Opaque Expressions in section 8.3.4.2 was helpful.